# What is the Jacobi tensor?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

On the Woldram Mathworld site, tgs Jacobi tensor is defined to be:

$J^m_{ijk} :=1/2( R^m_{ijk} + R^m_{kji})$

where $R^m_{ijk}$ is the Riemann curvature tensor.

I've not been able to find anything else about this tensor online. What is it useful for and what has Jacobi to do with it?

Comment: It's usually called the Jacobi operator and it is what comes out of the formula for the second variation.

Comment: the set of [Jacobi fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_field) represents the Jacobi tensor, see [Jacobi tensors and Ricci curvature](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01420210.pdf)